# Difference Between Zend Php/Zend server and simple php/Wamp server

Tags: php, eclipse, wamp, zend-studio, zend-server

I am beginner and wanna to learn few things before i start php dev/learning . What is the difference between Zend Studio/Zend server and simple Eclipse Php (PDT)/wamp server..

Where we should use Zend and where we should the simple Php/wamp.

Can we get same things with both of these or there is technological difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this will sound like a marketing answer now.

The main difference is that [Zend Server CE is a fully integrated stack offering](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/index)

> - Bytecode accelerator (Optimizer+)
> - Zend Data Cache
> - A certified PHP distribution
> - Zend Framework
> - Apache (or IIS integration)
> - MySQL (on Windows and Mac OS X)
> - Out-of-the-box connectivity to all common databases
> - Java code connectivity
> - Web-based PHP administrator console

out of the box with [Zend Studio being able to hook into that easily](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/features#serverint):

> - Auto Detection of Local Zend Server
> - Servers View
> - Zend Server Events List
> - Import and Debug Zend Server Event
> - Easy Project Creation on Zend Server
> - Quick Debug Mechanism
> - Debug & Profile Events
> - Zend Server API
> - Code Tracing import and viewing

The [commercial package of Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/editions) extends this with some additional features.

But, afaik, all of the above can be achieved [with more or less the same features](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/comparison) with non-Zend technology as well. You just have to put more work into it to get it running.

Comment: @Gordon Thx for ur reply, I had downladed the Zend studio 8 and not Zend server as it asks for license which i cant afford at learning place. Can i use Wamp as server in place of Zend server in Zend studio.

Comment: @Shabir Yes, you can. A Wamp will not have the same features as listed above out of the box. But Zend Server **CE** is free. So you dont need a license unless you buy the commercial version.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you very much for your support. Do i need to search Server CE for download

Comment: @Gordon During Installation Zend Server CE asked to either Install Apache server or configure IIS... If i let it to configure the IIS does it mean i will not be in requirement to install the Apache server?

Comment: @Shabir yes, like I said in the answer. It's a full stack. It will also install MySql for you and a bunch of other things.

Comment: @Gordon, I am not able to find like PhpMyAdmin to create the database.. May i know where to find it...

Comment: @Shabir it does not include something like that. You have to install that yourself or use a client like SqlYog (which is much nicer than phpmyadmin anyways)